Create anomynous accounts and forms
I need to create a portal where by people can fill out a form with some information, that information then gets sent to an email address, then the user receives a username and password so they can log back into the portal and await a reply to come in.
So when they go to the page to start with, it will have either a login user and password, or it will have button to go to a form. I can make the form with wpforms or what have you, and if i dont have a login page, then it will send off anonymously and thats fine, but I need a way for the other side to reply to that person, and I think by having a random username and password created for them after they send the form off, it will give them a way of logging back in anonymously to then see the reply.
Is there a way of doing this?
Or maybe i create a login page which auto assigns a username and password, and then once they are in, they can see a place to fill out a form, and then they can log back in to see a reply, maybe use a ticketing system?
To understand the use of this, it is so that people within a work place can send hr an anonymous message to report something, and they can then get a reply about it too.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There's probably a number of different ways of doing this.  However, you're going to struggle with the anonymity portion because if the system is sending user credentials to their account, it'll still have a record of the email, so in theory, it'll never be anonymous because the user->email connection will always exist.  Then, if the system is letting the person see the response, that means we need to send them an email - so the system will never actually be anonymous.
